# Using LaTeX to draw time series graphs and histograms

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, beamer, pgfplots

I have some graphs I drew in maple, some simple line plots and histograms. Now I'd like to redraw these graphs in LaTeX, so I can do fancy stuff in beamer like have one histogram appear, and then another on top of it on the next slide.

I guess one way to do this would be using R and sweave, but learning R seems like overkill, since I'm not really doing any statistical analysis: I just want to plot some data. Is there a simpler way to pass LaTeX the data in such a way that it will be able to plot the data in, say, a TikZ picture (since I already know how to use TikZ a bit...)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The [`pgfplots`](http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/pgfplots.pdf) package might be what you need. It is based on Tikz, and lets you plot data or functions.

Comment: OK, pgfplots looks nice, is there an easy way to input data from an external source? Or should I just export the data as CSV and `\input` that?

Comment: I've haven't used it much myself, and not for that purpose, but look at the manual, sections 4.2.2 and 4.2.3 ("Reading coordinates from files" and "Reading Coordinates From Tables").

Comment: `pfgplots` happily reads from external data files. The manual has a number of examples.

Answer (score 3):

pstricks extension and more specifically pst-plot package [pst-plot guide](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/graphics/pstricks/contrib/pst-plot/pst-plot-doc.pdf) may be a good solution as well. It is also a bit problematic if you use the pdflatex engine but works very well with dvips and ps2pdf.

Answer (score 3):

A half hour spent learning R is all you'll need.  If you can work in maple, you'll find R to be simple.  The good thing is that R and maple do quite different things, so time spent learning a bit of R will not be lost time.  If you do *any* work with data, R is a tool you should investigate.

Comment: But I wouldn't be able to use R to generate the data, right? (I was using Maple to iterate the logistic map and create time series from that...)

Comment: Sorry, your original post ("I just want to plot some data") suggested that you have the data in a file, and wanted to read the file and plot it using latex.  I don't know much about regenerating data in latex, but I know for sure that you could do such a thing in R.  I think you should google "cran logistic map" and start reading what you get. If you need a quick solution, of course the best plan is to make Maple create a graph, and use includegraphics{} in latex to typeset it.  That is the normal way to do things.